# merge values from pluck and combineLatest inside map rxjs

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I've a prop of `addHandler` passed to `AddTodo` component from `App.js`. Then inside `AddTodo` handler I'm not sure how do I combine pluck and map so that I've value from pluck as well as `combineLatest` merged inside `map`

Here's my code

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { componentFromStream , createEventHandler } from "recompose";
import { combineLatest } from "rxjs";
import { map, tap } from "rxjs/operators";
import AddTodo from './AddTodo/AddTodo';

import Todos from './Todos/todos';
// import User from './User/User';

const App = componentFromStream(prop$ => {
    const { handler: onAddHandler, stream: clickStream } = createEventHandler();
    const value$ = clickStream.pipe( tap(input =>
        console.warn(input)
        ));

    return combineLatest(prop$, value$).pipe(map(([props, value]) => <div>
          <AddTodo onAddHandler={onAddHandler}  />
          {/* <input placeholder="Add TODO" onChange={handler} /> */}
          <Todos todo={value} />
        </div>));
});


export default App;
```

**AddTodo.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { combineLatest } from "rxjs";
import { componentFromStream, createEventHandler } from "recompose";
import { pluck, map, startWith, tap } from "rxjs/operators";

const AddTodo = componentFromStream(prop$ => {
  const {
    handler: onChangeHandler,
    stream: inputStream
  } = createEventHandler();
  const value$ = inputStream.pipe(
    map(e => e.target.value),
    startWith("")
  );

  return combineLatest(prop$, value$).pipe(
    map(([props, value]) => (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Add Todo..."
          onChange={onChangeHandler}
        />
        <button onClick={() => {}}>Add todo</button>
        {/* <button onClick={() => onAddHandler(value)}>Add todo</button> */}
      </div>
    ))
  );
});

export default AddTodo;
```

Inside `AddTodo.js` inside map I probably I'm looking for something like

```
  return combineLatest(prop$, value$).pipe(
    pluck('onAddHandler'),
    // and use this value plus the belo values inside map
    map(([props, value]) => (
```

Comment: `pluck` is used to pick a single property from an object, but I'm not sure this is the way you want to use it. Can you make a demo on stackblitz showing what input and output you expect?

Comment: Yeah. You are right.  so I'm assuming `onAddHandler` is plucked from props. I'm just building a TODO app. Specifically stuck to passing a prop (addHandler in this case).

Comment: In case you need the link sure - here is the repo - https://github.com/kushalmahajan/ReactTsRxTodoApp.git

Answer (score 0):

all your need to do is move `pluck` inside `combineLatest` which look like this, then you 
 should get the onAddHandler in the map operator:

```
return combineLatest(prop$.pipe(pluck('onAddHandler')), value$).pipe(
  map(([onAddHandler, value]) => (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Add Todo..."
        onChange={onChangeHandler}
      />
      <button onClick={() => {}}>Add todo</button>
      {/* <button onClick={() => onAddHandler(value)}>Add todo</button> */}
    </div>
  ))
);
```